# Node is not launching

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I'm desperately trying to make node.js work again on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I installed it before 2-3 weeks ago and everything went fine, I used it daily for that period of time.

But today, suddenly it just wouldn't work anymore. The way it bugs is really strange :

- `node -v` works and returns v0.8.2
- the `node` command works too, I can access the console and do a `console.log`
- but when I use node with a file like this `node server.js`, Ubuntu just goes to a new line :

> kollektiv@kollektiv-PC:~/node-projects$ node server.js
>
> kollektiv@kollektiv-PC:~/node-projects$

I already reinstalled Ubuntu this evening but I get the same result.

I also did multiple `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update` in case some node.js dependencies would be out of date.

The way I installed node.js is by compiling the source following this tutorial : --> [Compiling Node.js from source on Ubuntu 10.24 - shapeshed](http://shapeshed.com/compiling-nodejs-from-source-on-ubuntu-10-04/)

I even did a `chmod 777 server.js` on the server file just to be sure but that didn't change anything either.

Thank you a lot in advance for your help !

EDIT : Content of server.js

```
var net = require('net'),
    server = net.createServer();
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    shasum = crypto.createHash('sha256');

var alpha = [],
    i = 0,
    cle = '';
while(i < 256) {
    alpha.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    i++;
}

// CRYPTAGE -- START --

function cryptProcess(cle, txt) {
    var k = txt.length,
        j = k / cle.length,
        cledeBase = cle,
        txtc = '',
        i = 1;
    while(i < j) {
        cle = cle + cledeBase;
        i++;
    }
    function crypt(cleu, letr) {
        //if(alpha.indexOf(letr) == -1) return "§";
        var biIndex = alpha.indexOf(letr) + alpha.indexOf(cleu), x;
            sumIndex = biIndex - alpha.length;
        x = sumIndex >= 0 ? alpha[sumIndex] : alpha[biIndex];
        return x;
    }
    while(k--) {
        txtc = crypt(cle[k], txt[k]) + txtc;
    }
    return txtc;
}

function decryptProcess(cle, txtc) {
    var k = txtc.length,
        j = k / cle.length,
        cledeBase = cle,
        txt = '',
        i = 1;
    while(i < j) {
        cle = cle + cledeBase;
        i++;
    }
    txt = '';
    function decrypt(cleu, letc) {
        //if(alpha.indexOf(letc) == -1) return "§";
        var biIndex = letc - alpha.indexOf(cleu), x;
        x = biIndex >= 0 ? alpha[biIndex] : alpha[biIndex + alphabet.length];
        return x;
    }
    while(k--) {
        txt = decrypt(cle[k], txtc[k]) + txt;
    }
    return txt;
}

// CRYPTAGE -- END --


server.on('connection', function(client) {

    var connecOne = 0;

    function talk(data) {
        var msg = data.toString('utf8');
        var msgEnc = cryptProcess(cle, msg);

        client.write(msgEnc);
        console.log(msg + '\nsend as\n' + msgEnc);
    }

    client.once('data', function(data) {

        function triHandShake() {

        }

    });

    client.on('data', function(data) {

        var msg = data.toString('utf8');
        if(connecOne === 0) {
            connectionOne(msg);
            connecOne++;
        }
        else if(connecOne === 1) {
            // Check for paragraph symbol
            //authentification with cookie as cle
        }

        var msgDec = decryptProcess(cle, msg);
        console.log(msgDec + '\nreiceved as\n' + msgDec);

    });

    client.on('end', function() {
        connecOne = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: I edited my answer with the content of server.js. I think that it is perfectly valid node.js code though.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `server.listen` call to actually listen for client requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [server.listen](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) to listen for connections and start the process as expected.

```
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem ! It is strange though that node only aborted the program and went on a new line compared to throwing an error. Again thank you very much !

Comment: It didn't abort, it just ended because you didn't make any calls to actually wait on anything.